# How do i print the path to a node in C++ if the nodes only contain pointers to their parents?

Tags: c++, tree

The task was to make a kind of file system in c++, where the user can create, remove, cd into and out of folders and list subfolders. After every operation the program should print out the path to either the current folder or the created/removed folder. I stumbled on the path printing:

```
struct dir
{
        std::string name;
        dir* parent;
};
std::string path(dir* a)
{
        if(a->parent==NULL) return "";
        return path(a->parent) +"/"+ a->name;
}
```

Example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
struct dir
{
        std::string name;
        dir* parent;
};
std::vector<dir> sys;
dir* currentdir;
std::string path(dir* a)
{
        if(a->parent==NULL) return "";
        return path(a->parent) +"/"+ (*a).name;
}
int main()
{
        sys.push_back({"",NULL});
        sys.push_back({"a",&sys[0]});
        sys.push_back({"b",&sys[1]});
        sys.push_back({"c",&sys[2]});
        sys.push_back({"d",&sys[3]});
        sys.push_back({"e",&sys[4]});
        sys.push_back({"f",&sys[5]});
        sys.push_back({"g",&sys[6]});
        sys.push_back({"h",&sys[7]});
        sys.push_back({"i",&sys[8]});
        currentdir = &sys[9];
        std::cout << path(currentdir);
 }
```

This gives the output `////////h/i` instead of `/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i`

Comment: _"Its as if a->name is being completely ignored."_ Well, did you check with the debugger, that `a->name` actually resolve to a non empty value?

Comment: I'm on it. I also just noticed that sometimes `a->name` throws an error and sometimes doesnt, while `(*a).name` never threw an error. I've used both to no success, and i will use the latter.

Comment: `a->name` is preferred, but `a->name` and `(*a).name` behave *identical* when `a` is a pointer, as it is in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you push new elements into `sys` it will eventually fill up and have to reallocate its elements, at that point all the pointers you've saved into `parent` become invalid and your program has undefined behaviour.

An easy solution would be to call `reserve` before creating any elements, you'll need to ensure you never exceed the reserved capacity otherwise you'll have the same problem again.

Another option would be to store an index into the `sys` array instead.

Comment: Storing the index of the parent into the struct helped, though i did have to modify all the functions. I guess i should have gone to that first. Thanks!